# ActiveJob instance freezes RSpec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an `after_create_commit` callback on my model, Foo, which looks like this:

```
after_create_commit { LogBroadcastJob.perform_later self }
```

I've reduced my `perform` method to return `nil` to simplify things.

When I create a Foo instance in an RSpec test with factory_girl, the test suite freezes. This only happens when I test models with that callback.

```
FactoryGirl.create :foo
```

When I **Ctl+C** out of my test suite it fails to kill the process. I have to find the process, which is still using my database (Postgresql), and kill it, which means that I don't see any errors on the command line. If I run my test suite again, it creates another process that I have to find and kill.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? How would I find useful errors here?

Maybe relevant: I upgraded from Rails 4.2 to 5.0.0.1 a while back.

Comment: Rails 5 changed some pieces around concurrency. If any of the dependencies you're using are creating threads, you might be running into issues with class reloading. [More info on this here.](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/concurrency-in-rails-5-0/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a concurrency issue. Thanks to the resource provided in @coreyward's comment, I was able to clear this up by setting **config/environments/test.rb** to

```
config.eager_load = true
```

This differs from my config in **config/environments/development.rb** (and everything works in development), so I can't say I understand yet why it works. But I can now run all my tests with `bundle exec guard` or `bundle exec rake spec`.